# How to Read Mail from specific string position and get data in JAVA mail API

Tags: java, string

I am reading multiple mails using JAVA mail API. Reading process working fine. Now as body content of mail , I am getting something like :

```
Congratulation , You just bought new item. Details are given below :

Condition: New
Condition note: Brand New - We have fast shipping!
Listing ID: xxxxxxxx
SKU: TX969666
Quantity: 1
Order date: 01/08/2016
Price: $14.95
Shipping: $0.00
```

Now , My task is to get all SKU only from each and every email. How can I get only SKU value from this mail content?

I am trying condition like :

```
Multipart mp = (Multipart) messages[i].getContent();
int multiparts = mp.getCount();
BodyPart Body = mp.getBodyPart(0);

String Content = Body.getContent().toString();

if (Content.contains("SKU:")) {

    int index = Content.indexOf("SKU:");
    System.out.println(index);

}
```

By above code , I can reach upto **SKU:** , How can I get Whole data of **SKU:**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got answer and it is solved by **Substring** function , Answer is :

```
if (Content.contains("SKU:")) {

    int index = Content.indexOf("SKU:");
    String SKU = Content.substring(index, index + 15);
    System.out.println("Product SKU is : " + "" + SKU);

}
```

It worked for me : `substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)`

Answer (score 2):

You might want to investigate **regular expressions** also.

With a pattern of

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile  ("SKU: ([^\\s]+)");
Matcher m = p.matcher  (Content);
if (m.find ()) {
  String sku = m.group (1);
  System.out.println ("Sku: " + sku);
}
```

You'd have a tool far more poweful than substring alone.

Comment: Ahh, So it will remove space from string, right? can you please explain in short that what is use of `Pettern` and `Matcher` here? So I can understand use of it.

Comment: I am getting error : `Unclosed group near index 12
SKU: ([^\s]+`
            ^

Comment: Sorry - editing on mobile is bad... will explain in a while